# Single image import from stack via FTP connection

Tags: import, image

**Background**

I would like to create a `CDF` document that is embedded on a webpage. The `CDF` will contain some image display elements and upon pressing a button a specific image from an image stack will be displayed. The data will be located on a FTP server where the images are loaded from. Unfortunately, I cannot provide access to the FTP since it is protected with password.

**The problem**

To speed up the process of importing single images from a stack I came across the option `"ImageList"` for `Import`:

```
Import["R:\\...Largetest1.1.tif", {"ImageList", 5}]
```

which does exactly what I want. It directly imports only the fifth image of the image stack. My test stack here is located on a local hard drive and contains 101 images of image dimensions 600x1000 pixels. The file size is about 118 MB. I checked for `AsboluteTiming` when importing the single image from the stack compared to the complete import. Depending on the current CPU load the timings differ a little bit.

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@Import["R:\\...Largetest1.1.tif", {"ImageList", 5}]
```

> 0.060000

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@Import["R:\\...Largetest1.1.tif"][[5]]
```

> 2.426500

Since the `Import` option works fine for image stacks on the local hard drive I want to use the same option when importing the same image via `FTP`. Unfortunately, this takes like forever which suggests that it doesn't import only a single image but rather the complete stack and then takes out the fifth image:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@Import["ftp://...Largetest1.1.tif", {"ImageList", 5}]
```

> 242.915000

When I import a single image via `FTP` it works quite fast:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@Import["ftp://...5Largetest1.1.tif"]
```

> 0.120000

**Attemps**

I then tried to find out what is happening and came across the function `ImageReadTIFF`. It seems to be possible to also specify import of a single image from a stack. However, the function fails when importing via `FTP`:

```
AbsoluteTiming@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF["R:\\...Largetest1.1.tif", {5}]
```

> {0.070000, {Image}}

```
AbsoluteTiming@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF["ftp://...Largetest1.1.tif", {5}]
```

> {0., {{$Failed, 1}}}

**Edit**
Unfortunately, this is also an issue when importing a single file from compressed archives such as `ZIP`. I tried to pack the single `TIFF` files from the above mentioned stack into a `ZIP` archive and then checked whether importing a single file works when the `ZIP` file is on my local hard drive and on the `FTP` server. The file size is reduced to about 36 MB upon compression compared to the 118 MB of the original image stack.

First@AbsoluteTiming[Import["R:\ ... .zip", "Image5.tif"]]

> 0.160000

First@AbsoluteTiming[Import["ftp://... .zip", "Image5.tif"]]

> 23.970000

It still semms to download the complete `ZIP` file first and then accesses the image when importing from `FTP`.

**Questions**

- Is there a fast way to import a single image form a stack via `FTP`? I mean, importing only one image of about 1 MB instead of importing the whole stack of 118 MB and then having to wait until the whole data is transferred.
- Is there a possible workaround I could use such that I do not have to import complete files or archives?
- Is it even possible to do such an import via `FTP`?

**No solution but**

After talking to some guys who know more about `FTP` protocols, I learned that the `FTP` protocol doesn't allow such operations. It is indeed necessary to download the whole `ZIP`/`TIFF` file and then access single files within the file afterwards. Unfortunately, I will have to find another solution for that. Anyhow, thanks for comments and ideas.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I don't think you can import anything into a CDF file...

Comment: @rm-rf: I checked for that and it worked ;) At least when importing via FTP.

Comment: Interesting... This opens up some possibilities :) btw, you're using the free and not the professional version, right?

Comment: Yes I am using the free version.

Comment: @rm-rf That's a backdoor for user input! Shhhh

Comment: @rm-rf I have already used this by giving the user instructions how to put images on a local http server and then she could quantify her data with a free CDF because importing from *the web* is allowed.

Comment: @g3kk0 : **Your idea is a pious hope.** ftp or http are for transfer, not for sophisticated file access (multi-page TIFF, ZIP archives, etc.). The latter is only achievable if a file resides in the respective file system you are working at. Even single page URL-based access for PDF files works the usual way: the whole file is downloaded and your browser plugin for PDF viewing selects the page you have specified, e.g. [PDF URL access](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=8). For multi-page TIFFs `Import` using ftp _has_ to fully load a file.

Comment: @UDB: Indeed ;) Thanks for the comment. I also figured that out and realized that this is quite obvious. However, I came up with a good workaround. Instead of accessing the multi-page tiffs, I wrote the functions to split, export and access the relevant data. I also zipped the images such that they can be accessed faster. This workaround is good enough for the task :)